# Simple Dataflow job stuck when using Scio and BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, spotify-scio

(4ea13f859044f090): Workflow failed. Causes: (4ea13f859044f04d): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.

I have no idea why my job failed, is there something in your logs ?

The job does a simple BQ query against a BQ table and then just tries to write the output to another BQ table using Scio 4.4

Comment: taking a look...

Comment: for some reason your workers are crash-looping. Figuring out what the reason is.